# how to change the SP2010 tab thumbnail?

Tags: 2010, design

How do i change the icon that is inside the red rectangle in this image?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your master page, there is a reference to the SharePoint shortcut icon

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_layouts/images/favicon.ico" />
```

That .ico file is the icon you see in your browser. You can update that item in the master page to point to your own custom .ico file.

HTH